# How to make a field optional in faccebook registration plugin

Tags: php, facebook, json, plugins, registration

I have the following code for my Facebook Registration Social Plugin:

```
 <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
         client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&
             redirect_uri=http://www.pingxxxxxx.com/facebook_registration_plugin/fbwe/trial.php&
             fields=[
 {'name':'name'},
 {'name':'email'},
 {'name':'location'},
 {'name':'gender'},
 {'name':'birthday'},
 {'name':'about',      'description':'About Youtself',             'type':'text'},
 ]"
     scrolling="auto"
     frameborder="no"
     style="border:none"
     allowTransparency="true"
     width="100%"
     height="330">
 </iframe>
```

**I want to make the last field i.e "about" optional to the user**. This field

```
     {'name':'about',      'description':'About Youtself',             'type':'text'},
```

Can anyone tell me how this can be done ?

Comment: Does the plugin not allow you to simply leave that field blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a field optional, you can use the no_submit parameter, as documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/

Using the flow documented on that page, you'd save the optional fields to a cookie through the Javascript validation callback. Then, when the user comes back to your site after auth-ing through Facebook, you can pick up and reassociate the data in the cookie with their account.

As far as I'm aware, every field that gets sent to Facebook must be present.